# Akka-http-session + cluster. Possible?

Tags: scala, cluster-computing

I am using [akka-http-session](https://github.com/softwaremill/akka-http-session) for storeing authorization fact in my disptributed app. I noticed some problem: if I create session(log in) on one node, I can't read it on another(User info is not aviable).

Session sends via cookies and stores on the client side. It's `akka-http-session` library mechanism, not mine. I guess, some part of the session stores on the server, so node can't validate cookie session created by another node.

Is there any way to solve this problem in a idiomatic manner?

Comment: We need more details. How are you creating the session? In memory,  in db, serialised on the client? What kind of access are you expecting from the other node? Sessions are mostly intended to store client state between  client requests...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am added some details in my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's my fault. The problem reason is - my nodes have different uri's. Cookies belongs to the certain uri, and there is no auth cookie on another uri.

My solution is to use balancier(e.g. nginx) and request my app via one balanciers uri.

Sorry for this silly question. =(